# Bounding an Integral with M-L Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I am stuck trying to understand Lemma 5.20 from Newman Bak's Complex Analysis.

**5.20 Lemma**

Let s denote a root of the equation $z=g(z)$, for some analytic function g such that $g'(s)=0$. Suppose that $z_0$ belongs to a disk of the form $D(s; r)$ throughout which $|g''(z)|\le M$ and let $z_1=g(z_0)$. Then $|z_1-s|\le \frac{1}{2} M|z_0-s|^2$

**Proof**

We begin by noting that $z_1-s=g(z_0)-g(s)$=$\int_{s}^{z_0} g'(z)dz$. But for any value of z on the line segment $[s,z_0]$, we can write:

$$|g'(z)|=|g'(z)-g'(s)|=|\int_s^z g''(z)dz|\le M|z-s|$$

Let $\Delta z=\frac{(z_0-s)}{n}$ and write

$$\int_s^{z_0}g'(z)dz=\int_s^{s+\Delta z} g'+\int_{s+\Delta z}^{s+2\Delta z}g' +...+\int_{z_0-\Delta z}^{z_0} g'$$

Then applying the M-L formula to each of the integrals above and using estimates for g'(z), show that $\int_s^{z_0} g'(z) dz$ is bounded by

$$\sum_{k=1}^n Mk(\Delta z)^2=M\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{|z_0-s|^2}{n^2}$$
and the lemma follows by letting $n\to\infty$.       $\square$

It is the last part that I don't understand. How do we bound $\int_s^{z_0} g'(z) dz$ by this sum?

Comment: Can you clarify if the last line reads .. $x \to \infty$ ?

Comment: My mistake! I meant to write the limit as n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why we want to do all that. Take $s=0$ just for simplicity. We then have $g$ analytic in $D(0,r)$ with $g(0)=0=g'(0)$ and $|g''|\le M$ in this disc. Let $z \in D(0,r).$ Then, using standard line-segment contours, we get

$$g(z)-g(0) = \int_{[0,z]}g'(w)\,dw = \int_0^1zg'(tz)\,dt$$ $$ = \int_0^1z(g'(tz)-g'(0))\,dt = \int_0^1z\int_0^1(tz)g''(u(tz))\,du\,dt.$$

Now crash through with absolute values and use the estimate on $|g''|.$ We get

$$|g(z)-g(0)| \le  \int_0^1|z|\cdot|zt|\cdot M\,dt = M|z|^2/2.$$

Comment: Thanks! This is much easier! I still am new at line-segment contours. How did you get  $\int_0^1zg'(tw)\,dt=\int_0^1z(g'(tz)-g'(0)\,dt$? (i.e. how did $g'(wt)$ become $g'(zt)$)? Also, I am a bit confused about the equality of integrals on the second line. Can you elaborate as to how $g'(tz)-g'(0)=\int_0^1 (tz)g''(u(tz))du$?

Comment: You're welcome. After the second = sign it should be $g'(tz),$ not $g'(tw).$ I'll correct that. This comes from the straight line parameterization $w=tz.$ In the same way, $g'(v) - g'(0) = \int_{[0,v]}g''(\zeta)d \zeta = \int_0^1vg''(tv)\,dt.$ Substitute appropriately and you'll get the above.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again!